# Only ubuntu is asking for EFI partition during installation , this should be a bug right?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

During the installation of ubuntu 22.04 , installer was asking for a EFI partition despite of having windows 10 on that same drive on MBR partition using legacy BIOS.

(live usb was made using rufus with MBR support, even tried with balenaetcher)

I downloaded other distros and rechecked. only **ubuntu and kubuntu** are not accepting MBR partition but i can easily dual boot on my pc with **mx linux, manjaro and pop os**.

if during installation i allow ubuntu to erase my disk then it converts my ssd to GPT partition table and installs it with EFI partition. **(even though ubuntu live usb boots as legacy system)**

as the other distros dont have any problem in dual boot on MBR partition with exact same settings, then does it mean there is some bug with ubuntu installation?

Comment: Did you boot the USB as a legacy BIOS device?  How did you flash the ISO?

Comment: As provided, I cannot say clearly what your issue is. The results will vary on what ISO you used, how your wrote the ISO to your installation media, plus the options used for your install. You may (*or may not, again depending on specifics as to what I stated & install options selected*) get a warning that Ubuntu 22.04 LTS may not boot - but it's a warning & not error message.  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ISOs do not require EFI partition (*you didn't provide ISO specific details; as there are many with installers using `ubiquity`, `subiquity` & `calamares` for 22.04)

Comment: USB booted as legacy bios device, i downloaded 22.04 LTS iso from official website. i tried flashing through Rufus(MBR) as well as balenaetcher. during installation i selected 'something else' to manually select the free space on my SSD.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has many ISO options; Server, Desktop, & flavors; the ISO controls what installer is on them, but your mention of *Something else* isn't available on all (`calamares` ISOs refer to it as "*Manual Partitioning*") will cause I believe a warning that the install may not boot; but it's a warning only & doesn't prevent boot/install.  ISOs with `ubiquity` do **not** have to install with EFI partition either (`calamares` ISOs won't install one by default on a BIOS box)

Comment: iso is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop (64 bit), problem is same when using Kubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop(64 bit). During manual partition there is no option to create '/boot' partition only '/efi' partition can be made. so i dont think its just a warning.

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 & Kubuntu 22.04 both use `ubiquity` installer (Kubuntu uses a Qt5 skin changing the look of `ubiquity`), but I know you can install without EFI partition as I verified install on a system where EFI partition wasn't possible (QA prior to release), but it wasn't recently.  The results will vary depending on how you wrote the ISO to your installation media (easiest if you *clone* ISO to media & don't re-format as some writes do, as non-cloned can cause EFI partition detection to be triggered - but that's controlled by the person writing ISO to media)